# Is it possible to run Elasticsearch and Magento 2 on different server?

Tags: elasticsearch, server-setup, magento2.4.2, hosting

I have a question and still considering it now. I have **Magento 2.4.2** running on cloud hosting but in the way I found an issue with installing **ES**. cause **ES** not support install on **shared/cloud hosting**.

So, I have a plan to install **ES** in **VPS server**. after that, I will connect this ES with **Magento 2.4.2** which already running on **shared/cloud hosting**.

Is it possible to run **Elasticsearch and Magento 2.4.2** on different servers? Please help. very frustrating on this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a different host as an elastic server. You have to hostname at Admin setting area.

Comment: That's great. thanks mate. But i will go with vps 2 core + 2/4GB ram, is it enough for elasticsearch?

Comment: 4Gb... But it depends on no of product you have also no of attribute you have

Comment: Great! thanks again mate. really appreaciate it. i will go proceed configure with vps.

Comment: Hi @Amit, i found issue with connected or remote host, last night i have done installation ES on my vps, and reconfigure elasticsearch.yml like this  : transport.host: localhost 
transport.tcp.port: 9300 
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0, and i try open ssh in cloud hosting and command indexing still not working, did you have any idea about this issue? thx Amit